# Python 3.8.6. SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement. Как только пишу else:

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Написал:

```
a = 10
if a > 10:
 print("more")
 else:
```

После "else:" нажимаю Enter, и выдаёт ошибку:

[image: Вот так выглядит ошибка]

*Помогите, как решить?*

Comment: А больше кода точно нет до того? Сильно похоже на незакрытую скобку, кавычку, или лишнюю запятую выше по коду

Comment: Ну а так то `else:` должно быть с таким же отступом, что и `if ... :`

Comment: И ещё может быть, что вы вводите много кода в среду, которая понимает строки по одной

Comment: Пробовал по разному, как Вы пишите. Но та же ошибка. Может причина в том, что пишу в Python 3.8.6 Shell?

Comment: @ВладиславЩербина Ну да, shell видимо по одной строке понимает, попробуйте в файле записать программу и скормить её интерпретатору

Comment: В общем, вопрос в среде программирования. Перешёл на PyCharm, пишу всё то же, что вызывало ошибку, здесь - ошибки нету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большое спасибо за помощь.
В общем решил всё так.
Написал код сокращённым вариантом. Всё выполнилось без ошибок. Только загадка всё же осталась такой же для не сокращённого текста. Скорее всего Shell воспринимает только дозированную информацию так же, как и оказалось, коммандная строка linux, тоже.

Вот сам код:
`print("yes") if a==10 else print("another")`

Answer (score 1):

1. Лишний отступ перед блоком `else`
2. После else должно следовать какое-либо выражение (если вам ничего не требуется, уберите блок `else`)

Корректный вариант:

```
a = 10
if a > 10:
    print("more")
else:
    pass
```

Или же:

```
a = 10
if a > 10:
    print("more")
```

Comment: Не даёт после `else` что-то написать ниже. Если пишу в ряд после `else`, то та же ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

`else` надо без отступа относительно `if`

```
a = 10
if a > 10:
    print("more")
else:
    print("less")
```

Comment: Аналогичная ошибка: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Answer (score 0):

Причина в том, что написал где-то в другом месте, а потом скопировал в IDLE. Так делать не надо.

Comment: А если я скажу, что писал сразу в IDLE?)

Comment: То я не поверю. Потому что между строчками ``a = 10`` и ``if a > 10:`` в IDLE не была нажата кнопка Enter. Если бы она была нажата, то перед ``if a > 10:`` стоял бы запрос на ввод (``>>>``), но его нет. Значит код просто вставлен, а не введен в самой среде.

Comment: ну и если бы причина была в неправильном отступе перед else, то выдало бы другую ошибку. Ошибка у вас в строке a = 10, до else выполнение даже не доходит.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за разъяснение.